# Custom handling for error 500 in playframework2(java)?

Tags: playframework-2.0

In my Routes file i have done something like-
GET /error                                    Controllers.error.Error()

But it is giving compilation error. 
In my error.java i have done something like,

```
Public static error Error(Throwable t) 
{
Return internalservererror(views.html.myerrorpage.render())
}
```

I want to know what to write in routes file for error 500, and i also wanted to know whether server will keep a log of the errors occured, How it works?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the compilation error?

Comment: It is showing compilation error in Routes,value Error in not a member of error. and if i do something like Controllers.error.Error(Thow: t) then it will give- NOT found type t.

Answer (score 1):

You can override those in the Global object.

EDIT : with the controlled URL.

**GlobalScala** :

```
override def onError(request: RequestHeader, ex: Throwable) = {
   Redirect(routes.ErrorHandler.error())
}
```

**routes** :

```
GET /error      controllers.ErrorHandler.error()
```

Comment: Ya i have done that, and all other custom errors are working fine for me. i need to know about what to write in Routes?

Comment: That's the whole point. You can not know when or on what page an error will be thrown. What you have to do, is override the onError method and redirect to a Error controller if you want to personnalize the url.

Comment: U have given the Scala code above. Can you give me an example with java code?

Comment: @ahly212 it's from official docs: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaGlobal